# how to traverse grid elements in codedui? getting error while getting each cell's value

Tags: testing, gridview, coded-ui-tests, tablerow, htmlcontrols

HtmlDiv hd = new HtmlDiv(UINewTabWindowsInterneWindow);
            hd.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Id, "ContentPlaceHolder1_WebPartManager1_gwpucHorizontalAgentQueueGrid1_ucHorizontalAgentQueueGrid1_bottomWebPartHeaderMiddle1");

```
        HtmlControl htc1 = new HtmlControl(hd);
        htc1.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.TagName, "TABLE");
        UITestControlCollection collection = htc1.FindMatchingControls();


        foreach (UITestControl uitabs in collection)
        {

            HtmlTable ht = (HtmlTable)uitabs;
            UITestControlCollection temp1 ;
            if (ht.Id == "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_WebPartManager1_gwpucHorizontalAgentQueueGrid1_ucHorizontalAgentQueueGrid1_RadGrid1_ctl00")
            {                   

                HtmlControl htc_tr = new HtmlControl(ht);
                htc_tr.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.TagName, "TR");
                UITestControlCollection collection_tr = htc_tr.FindMatchingControls();

                UITestControl tr;
                for (int i = 0; i < collection_tr.Count; i++)
                {
                    tr= collection_tr[i];

                   // HtmlRow hr = (HtmlRow)tr;  //getting error not able to cntrol htmlol to html row
```

Comment: Perhaps `tr` is a `UIControl` that has a `HtmlRow` as a child element. I would try something like `TestContext.WriteLine(tr.GetType().ToString());` to learn more about the control hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that something is getting muddled after all of the conversions you're doing.  I've tried the following, and it should work for your scenario as well.

```
HtmlDiv htc1 = new HtmlDiv(UINewTabWindowsInternWindow);
htc1.SearchProperties["id"] = yourID;

HtmlTable table = new HtmlTable(htc1);
table.SearchProperties["id"] = "ct100_ContentPlaceHolder1...";

HtmlRow row = new HtmlRow(table);
row.SearchProperties["TagName"] = "TR";

UITestControlCollection rows = row.FindMatchingControls();

foreach (UITestControl myRow in rows)
{
    HtmlRow thisRow = (HtmlRow)myRow;
    // Do your thing here.
}
```

You may even be able to get away with performing whatever actions on your row you need to do without converting it from the UITestControl back to a row.  Most properties and methods of the row are available in the parent class.